# I want to input enter to stop my program, but ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:" " just appeared

Tags: python-3.x, input, int, valueerror

I want to build a circle that I can keep entering marks and add it to a list until I input "Enter" which means "", and this part of program will break and move on. But I stuck on this part, I have search about the ValueError, but it seems doesn't match my situation or I just don't get the point. Therefore I ask here, please help.

---

```
#display list
def dis_score():
    for item in score:
        print(item,end = " ")
    print()

#mainbody
score = []
while True:
    x = int(input("Enter the marks please:"))
    if (x>0):
        score.append(x)
    if (x == ""):
        break

print("before sorted:", end = " ")
dis_score()
n = len(score)-1

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n-i):
        if (score[j]>score[j+1]):
            score[j],score[j+1]=score[j+1],score[j]
print("sorted:", end = " ")
dis_score()
```

---

And there was what I entered and the result:
Enter the marks please：80
Enter the marks please：70
Enter the marks please：85
Enter the marks please：

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-5-fa9f906bfcf8> in <module>()  
9 score = []  
10 while True:  
---> 11 x = int(input("Enter the marks please："))  
12 if (x>0):  
13 score.append(x)  

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `int(input("Enter the marks please:"))` will always raise an exception (the one you're reporting) if the input value is not a valid integer.

What you can do is:

```
while True:
    s = input("Enter the marks please:")
    if s == "":
        break
    x = int(s)
    if x > 0:
        score.append(x)
```